# How to compare two arrays and see if they are identical?

Tags: c, arrays, compare

I am trying to compare 2 arrays element by element and see if they are identical. I can get it to work for all situations except for when the len=0. I can't seem to get it to say that two arrays a={} and b={} are identical.

This is what I have so far

```
int identical( int a[], int b[], unsigned int len )
{
  int same=0;
  for( unsigned int i=0; i<len; i++ )
  {
     if(len==0)
            {
              same=1;
            }

     if (a[i]==b[i])
            {
              same=1;
            } 

             else{
                  same=0;}
   }
return same;
}
```

Comment: Note that as soon as two elements are seem to be different, both arrays are different. All elements must be the same for the arrays to be the same.

Comment: `if(len==0)
            {
              same=1;
            }` : If `len` is 0,  for-loop is not executed. So `same=1;` will not be executed by this if-block.

Comment: Maybe you should start with `same=1` because the loop will never execute when len is 0.

Comment: Does this really work when the arrays are different?

Answer (score 5):

It's really simple

```
int identical(int *a, int *b, unsigned int len) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

As you see you don't need to iterate through all the values, once you find a single value that is not equal to it's counterpart in the other array you immediately return `0`, otherwise always return `1` including when `len == 0` because in that case there will be 0 iterations and the code will jump directly to the `return 1` statement.

Comment: Could shorten that with `if (a[i] != b[i]) return 0;`.

Comment: @Ryan Perhaps, I just don't like it that way because the code looks like a cascade, something silly but this way it's easier to spot the `return`s.

Comment: As requested by 5 people by now, I removed the `continue` statement and instead return right after checking `a[i] != b[i]`.

Comment: Shouldn't we tell the person first why is his code not working, it gives more insight.

Comment: In this case, I think we can give him another idea to solve the problem. My intention is to ignore the OP's approach completely as it's hard to understand. And unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi That is why i in my above answer told him why was he wrong.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Also Sir , i have one question to ask , one of my program is not working but i am afraid to ask as a question here , they just downvote everything

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that you wrote, let us step by step see what is wrong with it.Take For Example `len = 3` and `int a[3] = {1,2,3}` `int b[3] = {4,5,3}`, are these array same, no they are not.

It is considered a good practice to know why your code was not working, so Let us see what your code says about that.

**Your Code**

```
    int identical( int a[], int b[], unsigned int len ){

    int same=0;          //same is Initialised to 0

     for( unsigned int i=0; i<len; i++ ){

       if(len==0){       //As len is not zero this condition is not true

          same=1;
        }

      if (a[i]==b[i]){   //For i = 0 , a[0]!=b[0] same stays `0`
                         //Comes Another iteration a[1]!=b[1] same stays `0`
                         //Comes Last Iteration a[2]==b[2] if is executed same becomes 1

          same=1;
        } 

         else{
              same=0;}
       }

       return same;      //Function Returns 1


       }
```

So your code returns `1`, in the above case, and you know why so is it correct , no it is not , in your code, it compares two element and if they are same it changes `same = 1`, so in effect all it is telling you is if the last element is same or not, because loop execute and in the last stage if elements are equal, then `same = 1` if not then it is `same = 0`.

And for your `len = 0` condition, loop never executes then because of line `for( unsigned int i=0; i<len; i++ )`, `i = 0`, if `i<len` then loop starts, and for `len = 0` loop never starts.

What You should do is initialise a variable `same = 1`, and if the elements are not equal change it to zero and break the loop as one different element is sufficient to say that arrays are not same, if same comes out to be `1`, then you know that every element was same.

Below is the code

**After Correction**

```
 int identical( int a[], int b[], unsigned int len ){

  int same = 1;

  if(len==0)              //For len = 0 , we make another condition because 
      return same;        //below loop never executes for len = 0.


  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {

    if (a[i] != b[i]){

        same = 0;           //As Soon as a element differ same becomes 0 and loop break.
        break;

     }

    }
    return same;      //same = 1 returns if no element differ  
                      //same = 0 returns if a single element differ.
    }
```

Comment: In your example `a[2] != b[2]` because `3 != 1`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks For Pointing Out, Edited it. It was a mistake.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is it ok now ?